# Remove pattern from beginning of string using only Bash pattern matching

Tags: bash, shell, posix

Is it possible to remove a pattern from *only* the beginning of a string using Bash's built-in pattern matching and parameter substitution? (Bash 5.0.18)

Given the following array:

```sh
myparams=( --some-param -h --15 -q 100 )
```

I would like to loop through the elements and output the following (strip all `-`s from the front without affecting any that might come after). Desired output:

```
some-param
h
15
q
100
```

I am aware of [Bash Hackers Wiki - Substring removal](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) but I didn't see any way to do this.

Here is one failed attempt, *Almost* works, but `some-` gets clobbered:

```sh
$ for p in "${myparams[@]}"; do echo "$p ==> ${p##*-}" ; done
--some-param ==> param
-h ==> h
--15 ==> 15
-q ==> q
100 ==> 100
```

Another failed attempt, this time `some-param` becomes `someparam`:

```sh
$ for p in "${myparams[@]}"; do echo "$p ==> ${p//-}" ; done
--some-param ==> someparam
-h ==> h
--15 ==> 15
-q ==> q
100 ==> 100
```

Here's a working solution, but it relies on `sed` (tested with sed from macOS 10.15.7):

```sh
$ for p in "${myparams[@]}"; do echo "$p ==> $(sed 's/^-*//'<<<"$p")" ; done
--some-param ==> some-param
-h ==> h
--15 ==> 15
-q ==> q
100 ==> 100
```

And finally, here's a working method that uses `BASH_REMATCH` — is this the only builtin way?:

```sh
$ for p in "${myparams[@]}"; do [[ $p =~ ^(-*)?(.*) ]]; echo "$p ==> ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" ; done
--some-param ==> some-param
-h ==> h
--15 ==> 15
-q ==> q
100 ==> 100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an extended pattern and parameter expansion:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' "${myparams[@]##+(-)}"
```

- `+(-)` matches one or more dashes
- `#` removes the string only at the beginning of the value
- `##` matches the longest string possible
- Using an array as the parameter removes the prefixes from all its members

Comment: Is there a major gotcha or downside to putting `shopt -s extglob` in `.bashrc` as a default?

Comment: I've used it for years and haven't noticed any glitches.